# Conditionally format a cell based on all of the values of a range of cells

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create an editable calendar of availabilities, wherein people can input that they are available either during the day, at night, all day, or not at all.
I would like the calendar to automatically highlight days when there is an overlap of availability - say, when everyone is free at night, or some are free all the time and one only during the day.

I can do the former by using the formula `=AND(($C2:$G2)="night")` - when all five people input "night", it highlights as fully available. However, my problem is with the "All the time" variable.

How would I create a conditional format that highlights cell A2 (for example) when *all* of the cells in range C2:G2 are filled with *either* "day" *or* "both"? So far I've gotten to `=OR($C2:$G2="day",$C2:$G2="both")`, but this has the problem of highlighting A2 if even just *one* cell in the range has the desired value. I assume I have to include an AND command here, but how exactly?

Thank you for any help :)

[Screencap of calendar: Columns A and B are filled with days/dates. C1:G1 are labelled Person 1 - Person 5. Each person has filled an availability for each date, either "night", "day", "both", or "NA".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFt1u.png)

Comment: Thank you!! The COUNTIF solution is exactly what I was looking for :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would to be using a couple `COUNTIF()` functions and comparing to the total, in your case 5 since you have 5 columns.

Sum the results of the two `COUNTIF()` functions, if they equal 5, your data is highlighted:

```
=COUNTIF($C2:$G2,"day") + COUNTIF($C2:$G2,"both") = 5
```

Essentially, if the left side of your equation is equal to the right side then it will return `True`.

---

This can be a little more portable. Only need 3 or more of the 5 cells? You could simply change to `>= 3` instead of being `= 5`.

Answer (score 0):

In the event no one is able to come up with a more *elegant solution*, here's one that at least would work for you. Not too bad if you only need to compare the 5 columns, could be a bit more painstaking if you have more.

```
=AND(OR($C2="day",$C2="both"),OR($D2="day",$D2="both"),OR($E2="day",$E2="both"),OR($F2="day",$F2="both"),OR($G2="day",$G2="both"))
```

The `And()` function, as you are likely already aware, requires that each and every value within it returns a `True` value to have it output a value of `True`.